# Prevent loosing focus on div element with content editable type

Tags: reactjs, focus, contenteditable, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

```
      <div
        ref={ref}
        className={clsx(
          classes && classes.size,
          error && styles.error,
          styles.textarea
        )}
        data-text={placeholder}
        onInput={(e: any) => {
          const eventValue = e.target.innerText;

          const newValue = wrapper
            ? formatMessageWithParams(wrapper, { value: eventValue })
            : eventValue;

          setValue(name, newValue);
        }}
        contentEditable
        id="textarea"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: value }}
      />
```

I want to make rich text element , which are editable , and will show html string inside .I've tried to find out the ways how to render html string inside of div  - the way it can be done with `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` prop , also I found out that you can not work with `onChange` , handler which you should use is `onInput` . What is the problem I have , when I type something , it change value , by `setValue` function , on each button press, but field loose focus and carret stay on first line . How can I prevent it ? I've tried to make it by `ref.current.focus` , but it isn't work, `div` doesn't have `autoFocus` property , also I've tried to show value by `data-value` , but html then doesn't work  . Is there way to prevent loosing focus on `contentEditable` div element ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dawn-i75kg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It's loosing focus because your `<div` is getting re-rendered each time.

Comment: how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `useState` for `setValues`, try to use `useRef`, it would not re-render the component. And you can also use `onKeyDown` event to save data.

updated code:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const valueRef = useRef("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        data-text="write text here"
        className="rich-text"
        contentEditable
        onInput={(e) => {
          valueRef.current = e.target.innerHTML;
        }}
        suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: valueRef.current }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I can remember value in ref , but I want to show new content after each key press ) but text will be wrapped with html tags , it should change it

Comment: Try this. Inside div, {setValuesRef.current}

Comment: I've attached codesandbox link , you can show it there

Comment: see the updated answer. It is working.

Comment: I need render it in dangerouslySetInnerHTML , because I need html string inside

Comment: Code you showed just same value , but it isn't update anything inside of div , I need to get value , wrap it to some html tags , and show after each updated in this div , have you seen how rich text field work ?

Comment: see the updated answer. It gives innerHTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241068/discussion-between-andrey-radkevich-and-swimshahriar).